# PhpStom + XDebug + Codeigniter (MVC)

Tags: php, codeigniter, xdebug, phpstorm

I have a Linux development and testing server, that I use to create web app for my clients, before put the web app on the production server. The config of apache allow me to have "homedir" configuration, so every project has its "*/home/nameproject/public_html/*" directory, visible to the url *http://nameserver.org/~nameproject*
I work using *CodeIgniter* framework, and in the url there isn't *index.php* by using of *.htaccess* file, and *$config['url_suffix'] = '';*  in the *application/config.php*
***Remote Server***
SO: Debian
Apache: 2.2.16 
PHP: 5.3.3 with Suhosin-Patch v0.9.32.1
XDebug Version: 2.1.0
***Local***
IDE: PhpStorm 7.1
IDE Key: PHPSTORM
Server Configuration:
[image]
Server Configuration Mapping [image]
I Followed the guide [Zero-configuration Web Application Debugging with Xdebug and PhpStorm](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm), and when I start the debug session, whatever page I load, the debugger on my PhpStorm start and try to open the file *index.php*
Obviously, as I mentioned before, I haven't in the url any *index.php*...
***Scenario***: Click on the *Listen debugger connections button*, setting the breackpoint in the file: *"application/controllers/auth.php"* on the *"forgot_password"* function, and run the debugger on server,
 
The PhpStorm intercept the request and show me ever this screen
[image: incoming connection]
IMHO the *Request uri = /~nameproject/auth/forgot_password* cannot find the relation with *"File Path On Server"* that must be */home/nameproject/public_html/application/controllers/auth.php"* instead of = /home/nameproject/public_html/index.php
Some idea on how to call the controller php file instead the index.php ???

Comment: `Host` field in "Server Configuration" screenshot is wrong -- it should be just a host name and not a URL. My suggestion -- delete any existing "PHP | Servers" and use Zero-Config approach -- IDE will help setting it up. After you will have it set up properly we can look further. But right now IDE behaves correctly (3rd screenshot) by asking a path to `index.php` (no path mappings setup correctly so it stops in currently running file, which is index.php)

Comment: If I delete the existing PHP->Server configuration (have no more configuration), the behavior is the same.... the incoming Connection From Xdebug ask me if I want to debug the index.php files ... But incredibly !!! If I click on ***"accept"*** it maps in automatically the index.php to the file auth.php !!! Great now it works .... I click on the ignore button because I thought that I start my debug from /home/public_html/index.php !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accordingly to your comment .. the problem seems to be in **incorrect value of "Host" field in `Settings | PHP | Servers`** (1st screenshot) -- it should be just domain/host name and not actual URL (compare with "Server name" filed on 3rd screenshot) -- just remove `/~***` part. The path mappings seems to be set up correctly.

Alternatively -- just delete any entries in `Settings | PHP | Servers` and use Zero-Config approach -- IDE will help setting it up on first successful debug connection.

As for 3rd screenshot -- IDE behaves correctly. Because there is no correct path mapping (with correct server/host name) PhpStorm breaks at first line of currently running script, which is `index.php` (entry point into your MVC application). Once correct path mapping will be established, IDE will be stopping on breakpoints only (unless it matches some criteria in "Settings | PHP | Debug | Xdebug" section).